# Passing string array to a prepared statement

Tags: java, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/java-preparedstatement)

Can I make the prepared statement

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE STUDENT_ID IN ?
```

into

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE STUDENT_ID IN (1,2,3)
```

Given that the collection of student ids is a string array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best solution is going to be generate the in clause dynamically: `IN (?,?,?,?)` , and then calling `preparedStatement.setInt(i + 1, myValues[i])` for each value in your array/collection.   The bad news is you will end up with a different preparedStatement for each time you have a different number of values.

See duplicate question: [PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/alternatives-for-java-sql-preparedstatement-in-clause-issue)