# How to pass array of strings dynamically to SQL "IN" clause in Java?

Tags: java, sql

I have a array of Strings "String[]" with certain values. I want to pass that array dynamically to SQL "IN" clause something like:

```
Select * from Employee where emp_name in (?);
```

Here "?" has to replaced with String Array. I want to do this in Java Class. I tried with

```
Array array = conn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", new Object[]{"1", "2","3"});
pstmt.setArray(1, array);
```

But it is not working and getting exception "SQLFeatureException".

Thanks!!!

Comment: And also see [PreparedStatement with list of parameters in a IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3107044/2024761) which has a lot of dupes linked in it.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the field emp_name is not an array but a `VARCHAR` so when you set a value for it, it must be a String. So having only 1 `?` in the query represents a single possible value for emp_name. You would have to list as many `?`'s as the length of the array and substitute these individually with their values.

Assuming that empNames is a `String[]`, you could do this to prepare the query:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("Select * from Employee where emp_name in (");
for (int i = 0; i < empNames.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0) {
    query.append(",");
  }
  query.append("?");
}
query.append(")");
```

and this to set the individual values behind the `?`'s:

```
for (int i = 0; i < empNames.length; i++) {
  pstmt.setString(i+1, empNames[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can appy Select batching to resolve your problem. Reference:

[link](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2)

Comment: Link only answers not valid :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the query with IN clause by iterating the String array using StringBuilder.

I would recommend that don't get into complexity of using `Arrays.toString()` unless you really need that. There will not be much difference in the performance since both are needed to iterate the array to create the `String` literal.

In my approach we can have a good control over iteration of the array adding the **single quote** and **comma** etc.

Comment: Above solution is working. I want to just avoid that loop and want to pass String like 'ABC','DFD','ss' for "?" .. Is that possible