# how to send a list of integer values into prepared statement

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have been looking for sending a list of integer array into prepared statement, but i was unable to do it. can somebody help me do it.

my code as follows:

```
public int  Verify(int[] val) {
  try {
if (connection != null) {
    pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("select cola from tableA where val in(?)");
    pstmt.setInt(1, val);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

i know this wont work.can someone help me to send all values in array at one into "?".

Any help could be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that I prefer the most voted answer rather than the accepted answer.

Comment: I think you should use the setArray- Method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray%28int,%20java.sql.Array%29

Comment: @pL4Gu33 not all database engines support sending array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. To construct proper query you have to be careful while appending the last ? in the query string. One more problem I see is that you pass an integer array and you are trying to set Strings in psmt.

```
// Array of values to be passed in query
        String[] values;

        // Construct the query string first
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(
                "select cola from tableA where val in(");

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (i + 1 == values.length) {
                stringBuilder.append("?)");
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("?,");
            }
        }

        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(stringBuilder.toString());
        int i = 0;
        for (String value : values) {
            pstmt.setString(i++, value);
        }

        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

// Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause).

It would be the answer for this question. Just convert your array to `Arrays.asList(arrayVariable)` and do the process as mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: If you are not sure that your int[] contains unique values, try using a Set.

```
Set<Integer> valSet = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(val));
```

Step 2: You should either use Kannan's post or ... In your case where ? values are int only, I think that you can get rid of preparedStatement and you may use a simple statement as well, it seems to be safe.

Just create your query from the Set (or array)

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("SELECT cola FROM tableA WHERE val IN(");
for (Integer a: valSet) {
    b.append(a);
    b.append(",");
}
b.setLength(b.length()-1); //remove last comma
b.append(")");
String query = b.toString();
```