# How to extract Object[] and get it into query using preparedstatement setObject()?

Tags: java, oracle, model-view-controller

might be a silly question but I cant get the query running. This is my code:

```
ArrayList<Attraction> getAttraction(Object[] obj) throws SQLException
{

    Connection connection = facade.getConnection();

    ArrayList<Attraction> attractions = new ArrayList<>();

    // Check obj value
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(obj));

    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT attra.attractid,attractname,x,y,z,age,weight,"
            + "height,duration,price,status FROM attraction attra "
            + "INNER JOIN attrib_bridge ab ON attra.attractId = ab.attractId "
            + "INNER JOIN attribute attri ON ab.attributeId = attri.attributeid"
            + "WHERE attri.attributename IN ?");

    ps.setString(1, java.util.Arrays.toString(obj));

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 

    while(rs.next()){

        // Initialize attraction object
        Attraction attraction = new Attraction();

        attraction.setAttractionId(rs.getInt(1));
        attraction.setAttractionName(rs.getString(2));
        attraction.setxLocation(rs.getInt(3));
        attraction.setyLocation(rs.getInt(4));
        attraction.setzLocation(rs.getInt(5));
        attraction.setMinAge(rs.getInt(6));
        attraction.setMaxWeight(rs.getInt(7));
        attraction.setMinHeight(rs.getInt(8)); 
        attraction.setRideDuration(rs.getInt(9));
        attraction.setPriceRide(rs.getInt(10));
        attraction.setStatus(rs.getString(11));

        // Add new object to to movies
        attractions.add(attraction);
    }

    return attractions;
}
```

And this is the error I get :

> [Gentle rides, Thrill rides, Transport rides]
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in >your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version >for the right syntax to use near 'attri.attributename IN '[Gentle rides, Thrill >rides, Transport rides]'' at line 1
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293)
>       at com.ThemeParkG02.rs.control.manager.ManageAttraction.getAttraction(ManageAttraction.java:123)
>       at com.ThemeParkG02.rs.control.manager.Facade.getAttraction(Facade.java:85)
>       at com.ThemeParkG02.rs.control.listener.ViewAttractionListListener.run(ViewAttractionListListener.java:32)

---

I'm really dizzy right now. The values is out but I the query is not working. The '[' and ']' really blocking my goal. Any input guys?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I missed the issue of the `IN` clause, but my answer is technically correct, as the first error in the SQL is the missing space. The link provided by Miljen Mikic explains how to fix the `IN` clause issue.

Your error says:

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in >your SQL syntax
```

You are missing a space before `WHERE`.

**Updated**

For improved readability, I prefer writing it like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT attra.attractid, attractname, x, y, z, age" +
                           ", weight, height, duration, price, status" +
              " FROM attraction attra" +
              " JOIN attrib_bridge ab ON attra.attractId = ab.attractId" +
              " JOIN attribute attri ON ab.attributeId = attri.attributeid" +
             " WHERE attri.attributename IN ?";
try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setString(1, Arrays.toString(obj));
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            // Process row here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, it should be : 

" WHERE attri.attributename IN (?) "

Comment: @SkyvrawleR Actually, the `IN` clause issue is more complicated than that (see the link). You have to dynamically build the SQL with the correct number of markers `IN (?, ?, ?, ?)`, and then call `ps.setString(n, ...)` multiple times to set each value in the array.

Comment: The code runs but return 0. I test this query in navicat and its working with 3 rows of data. This is the tested query. 'SELECT DISTINCT attra.attractid,attractname,x,y,z,age,weight,height,duration,price,status FROM attraction attra INNER JOIN attrib_bridge ab ON attra.attractId = ab.attractId INNER JOIN attribute attri ON ab.attributeId = attri.attributeid WHERE attri.attributename IN ('Transport rides');'

Comment: @SkyvrawleR If your list contains 3 values ("A", "B", "C"), then `Arrays.toString` returns `[A, B, C]`, and `IN (?)` with `setString(1)` is equivalent to `IN ('[A, B, C]')`, which is same as `= '[A, B, C]'`, which is not what you want. What you want is `IN (?,?,?)` with `setString(1,"A"); setString(2,"B"); setString(3,"C");`.

Comment: lets say we dont know the size of the object[] , how will you solve that kind of situation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause, which was the second link in the answer provider by the "duplicate" message.