# check input for SQL-Injection with Mybatis

Tags: java, sql-injection, mybatis

I'd like to check my input string for potential SQL-Injection.

Here is my class, method and query:

```
public class UserNamesQuery {

   public static String getUserNames(Map<String, Object> params) {
       String userNames = (String) params.get("userNames");
       return "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name IN (" + userNames + ") ";
   }

}
```

Is there a tool or a quick way to validate that `userNames` is without SQL-Injection?

Notice that I use **Mybatis**

Comment: You probably want to use a `PreparedStatement` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Prepared statements is good advice, but this in an `IN` value list. [PreparedStatement with list of parameters in a IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause)

Comment: @AlexK. is correct - I have an issue with IN

Comment: Any issue can be solved using the proper way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. There is no way. And no need.

To be frank, there is no such thing like "SQL injection". There is only **an exploit of improperly formatted query**.

So, instead of hunting down whatever "injections" you have to format your queries properly, by means of using **prepared statements.**

Any data, depends on context, could be either a potential injection or a harmless chunk of text. So, with whatever filtering function there will be too much false positives. Worse yet, whatever filtering is a "black list" implementation, means it will **always** be incomplete - it's just impossible to filter out all the codes used to exploit an injection.

On the other hand, prepared statement is a relatively simple solution that will be **immune to any type of injection without even knowing them.** Just because it won't let the data to interfere with the query.

Comment: How would you purpose to overcome the IN in my query, and how can I apply it to mybatis?

Comment: And no problem with MyBatis there, since you can give the parameters as #{parameterName} which will be automatically translated into a prepared statement. For your IN clause, you typically use a foreach statement in the MyBatis mapping.

Comment: @Florian Schaetz how do I do that exactly? maybe you'll write it in a separate answer

Comment: To answer that question completely, I would have to reproduce the whole MyBatis documentation. Start with http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html , then have a look at http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#foreach - If there are more specific questions open after you tried that, simply ask them in a new question, since YCS' answer is completely correct for this one.

Comment: Just a little addition: Especially important for you is the chapter about parameters http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Parameters and especially String substitutions http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#String_Substitution (in short: Don't use them for user input, use parameters instead - and as an addition: NEVER, EVER build your query with user input. ). This article might also help somewhat: http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-mybatis

Answer (score 0):

Sanitizing input is not the way to prevent injections like this. Using prepared statements is the way to go.

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN (?)"); //Add however many ?'s you want, if you have an array you can use a StringBuilder for this to add more ?'s
ps.setString(1, userName);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

This will set the ? in the code to your string. The database driver then handles the rest.
If you have multiple values in the IN clause, use a StringBuilder and a loop to add more Questionmarks.

Also notice how the indexing starts with 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score -1):

mybatis sql template may be a good choose. FYI:

```
<sql id="orderTypeSql">
    <trim prefix=" ">
        <if test="orderType=='desc'">desc</if>
    </trim>
</sql>

<sql id="oderColumnSql">
    <trim prefix="order by " suffix="" >
        <choose>
            <when test="orderColumn==null or orderColumn==''"></when>
            <when test="orderColumn=='id'">
                id<include refid="orderTypeSql"/>
            </when>
            <when test="orderColumn=='name'">
                `name`<include refid="orderTypeSql"/>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </trim>
</sql>

<select id="testOrderBy" resultType="User">
    select
    id,
    `name`
    from t_user
    <include refid="oderColumnSql"/>
    limit 0, 10
</select>
```