# How to use IN clause with PreparedStatement in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have to write a SQL query for Postgres database as follows:

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE ename IN (?)
```

I want  to pass `ename` as list or string which will contain multiple employee names, e.g. `"abc, bcd, efg"`. How to set the values?

How to use `IN` clause with `PreparedStatement` in Postgres?

Comment: How to use IN clause with PreparedStatement in Postgressql ??

Comment: Use array instead: `where ename = any(<array parameter or constant here>)`. Funny, but PostgreSQL transforms `in` clause into `= any(...)`, internally, can see it in the query plans.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)

Answer (score 27):

There are several ways to do this. The clean way is to pass an array to the prepared statement. An alternative to Nick's answer is to pass a proper `java.sql.Array` value:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "DELETE FROM employee WHERE ename = ANY (?)");
String[] idList = new String[] {"abc", "bcd", "efg"};
Array ids = connection.createArray("varchar", idList);
pstmt.setArray(1, ids);
```

Another option is to use Postgres' string functions to convert the comma separated list to an array. That is probably the easiest way:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
     "DELETE FROM employee WHERE ename = ANY (string_to_array(?, ','))");
psmt.setString(1, "abc,bcd,efg");
```

Note that you **must not have spaces between the comma and the value**! Those spaces will be part of the value that is stored in the array after `string_to_array()` has done it's job so comparison would e.g. be `ename = ' bcd'` which would fail if there is no leading space in the column `ename`(which is highly likely)

Comment: Not only are spaces a problem, but if a comma is part of one of the values, you'll have trouble. From what I can tell, there's no way to escape it. The best option I can see is using `the_leafs_just_won_the_stanley_cup` as a delimiter, since that hasn't been true since before SQL was invented, so it wouldn't be one of the values.

Comment: Works good, minor change: I had to use `connection.createArrayOf` instead of `connection.createArray` (keep parameters the same). Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Like this:

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE ename = ANY(?)
```

The parameter should be formatted as an [array literal](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT), e.g. `"{abc,bcd,efg}"`.

Comment: The part about array literal formatting saved my day. I was trying to use in a prepared statement. Thanks

Answer (score -10):

You might want to try the below:

```
DELETE FROM employee 
 WHERE ename IN ('abc', 'bcd', 'efg')
```

Comment: I am using PreparedStatement,  we don't know how many records we need to delete. that will come dynamically. , so how use place holders, or if we can do with only one placeholder, then how to set the values as a List or String.???