# PostgreSQL: relationship between types given w/placeholders and types in PQexecPrepared() paramValues parameter

Tags: c, postgresql, prepared-statement, type-resolution

If I have a placeholder given as `$1::text`, does that means the corresponding `paramValues` that I pass to `PQexecPrepared()` needs to be a C-style string? So far I've done it that way and so far it's worked. (And so far, I've needed to give `::text` along w/the placeholder or I get an error). But what if I declare the placeholder as `$1:int`? Can I still give a C-style string in the `paramValues`? *Should* I give a C-style string? The [docs on this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/libpq-exec.html) are a bit vague and aren't very clear on what to do w/the `paramTypes` parameter of `PQprepare()` which I've left `NULL` anyway, so far.

More importantly, what if I need to express an array, like as `$1::text[]`? The docs say nothing of this and the solutions I've seen so far don't seem very efficient or even very reliable, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/36930781/1676382. So far I've been giving the values to `PQexecPrepared()` in "text" format, but should I be switching to "binary" and in what conditions?

So far I've been able to get away w/some pretty simple queries:

```
const char *query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col=$1::text";
const void *types = NULL;    //Wish I knew what could be assigned to an Oid
PQprepare(conn, name, query, 1, static_cast<const Oid *>(types));
```

...

```
const int *lengths = NULL;      //It doesn't seem like these vars are used for anything right now
const int *formats = NULL;
int result_format = 0;
//values is a const char * const * and is the return value of QScopedArrayPointer <char*>::data()
res = PQexecPrepared(conn, name, 1, values, lengths, formats, result_format);
```

Now so far this works, but what if I wanted to have

```
WHERE col = ANY ($1::text[])
```

? How would I express `values` that is passed to `PQexecPrepared()`?

My project is in GNU C++ using PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: That depends: Are you sending the parameters in text or binary format? Do you specify their types or not? Maybe it would help if you add a code sample to the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The question shows I'm specifying types. So far I'm doing it in "text" format, but another part of the question is that I don't know if I should be doing "binary" and in what conditions.

I'll work on code snippets.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific: how do the `paramTypes` and `paramFormats` arguments to `PQexecParams` look?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've included snippets explaining what I'm doing and what I want to do (but the short answer is that those parameters are `NULL`)

Answer (score 0):

If you sent untyped string arguments like in your example, they will have type `unknown` and converted to the proper type, if possible. This is quite similar to string literals in SQL statements.

It should not be necessary to cast to `text` in the SQL statement. I'd be curious what the type of `col` is if you find that cast necessary.

If you want to pass a `text[]` in text format, simply use its string representation, for example

```
{first element,two,three}
```

This will also work for integers and other types; just use the text representation of the value.

You can also use the `paramTypes` argument to `PQexecParams` to specify which type it is explicitly. The possible values are in the `oid` column of `pg_type`, and they are constant for system types.

Comment: I could have sworn that the `::text` was essential, but I can't duplicate the error that I got before. In any case, is this any better than https://stackoverflow.com/a/36930781/1676382? It seems the engine still has to parse a string and then there's the danger of what happens if the delimiter character appears in one of the values

Comment: Then you have to escape the entry with double quotes, and double quotes inside the entry with backslashes: `{entry one,entry two,"evil{,}\"entry"}`

Comment: My position here is to end shortly and my next won't involve any SQL at all, so I wont have a chance to really test it. My only challenge is: are you sure that covers all bases? I seem to remember looking into PostgreSQL escaping and found a case where it could all be unreliable.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is correct, but I agree that it is not nice to have to escape strings "by hand".