# Java adding Array of ids to preparedstatement for SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server

I work on a Java 1.7 project, with MSSQL SERVER.

I try to add an array of ids to a query:

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>(3);
ids.add("32123");
ids.add("4455");
ids.add("1258");
String sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM databaseName
WHERE id IN(?)";
Connection c = null;
PreparedStatement s = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    Object[] objArr = new Object[ids.size()];
    objArr = ids.toArray(objArr);
    c = bbbDataSource.getConnection();
    s = c.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
    Array array = c.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", objArr);
    s.setArray(1, array);
    rs = s.executeQuery();
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
Exception thrown bean: java.lang.abstractMethodError: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.proxy.ConnectionProxy.createArrayOf(LJava/lang/String:[LJava/lang/Object:)LJava/lang/Array;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason you've created an `Object[]` instead of a `String[]`?

Comment: I have the same error message with String[]

Comment: `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` should say it all: `createArrayOf(...)` is abstract, i.e. not implemented by `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.proxy.ConnectionProxy`. That might hint at a version conflict (the classpath might contain an older version of jtds) or only part of your application having been compiled.

Comment: Just for reference to @Thomas comment (not sure if exact this version of library is used however) : https://github.com/milesibastos/jTDS/blob/master/src/main/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbcx/proxy/ConnectionProxy.java#L702

Comment: thanks for your answers, so if I understand, I need to change this reference: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource , but to what exactly?

Comment: What did you derive `JtdsDataSource` from? The problem is in `ConnectionProxy`. You'll either need to find a version that supports `createArrayOf()` or use a different jdbc driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't use the createArrayOf method with the jTDS library. You'll have to use a different database driver library.

Evidence (code pulled from net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection):

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.sql.Connection#createArrayOf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])
 */
public Array createArrayOf(String typeName, Object[] elements) throws SQLException {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    throw new AbstractMethodError();
}
```

You could use something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server since you're using SQL Server.

Another option is OscarRyz's answer of [PreparedStatement with list of parameters in a IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause/36420956)

Comment: that's using version 1.3.1 of net.sourceforge.jtds