# Trim Java String and use in Sql Where Clause

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to get values from MySQL db using a query which gets values from a multiple select. The problem is that I am using `StringBuilder` to create the query based on the values I am getting. If you see the Where clause used why me, every time a new variable is fetched a comma is added in the end.

How do I remove the last comma added as it is giving me an error in the sql query. Will appreciate any help.

```
String[] stat = req.getParameterValues("status");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(200);

if (stat != null) {

    for (int i = 0; i < stat.length; i++) {

        sb.append("'" + stat[i] + "',");

    }

    String app = "WHERE status in (" + sb.toString() + ")";
    String sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM Table " + app + ";";
}
```

**Result Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
   WHERE status in ('Deployed','PendingDisposal','Available','Reserved','Broken',);
```

I want to get rid of the last comma after 'Broken'

Comment: You code is asking to be SQL injected. Sanitize inputs and use prepared statements.

Comment: Remember [the story of Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with comma in the end, you can append your Strings like this :

```
String del = "";
for (int i = 0; i < stat.length; i++) {
    sb.append(del).append("'" + stat[i] + "'");
    del = ",";
}
```

But in fact this is not really good idea to use this way, because it can cause SQL Injection or syntax error, you have to use PreparedStatement for example :

```
for (int i = 0; i < stat.length; i++) {
    sb.append(del).append("?");
    del = ",";
}

try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sb) {
    for (int i = 0; i < stat.length; i++) {
       ps.setString(i, stat[i]);
    }
    ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();//get results
    ...
}
```

Comment: Finally someone mentioned PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 1):

You can join a string array with commas using Java 8 streams:

```
String joined = Arrays.asList(stat).stream()
    .map(s -> "'" + s + "'")
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

But note that joining strings like this is a really bad idea: you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, e.g. if one of the element of `stat` is [something like](https://xkcd.com/327/):

```
'); DROP TABLES Table; --
```

You are better off building the query using a `PreparedStatement`. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause).

Answer (score 0):

Need to update your `for` loop where you need to append element from array till its second last element and append last element of the array outside the loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<stat.length-1;i++){  // loop till second last element
sb.append("'"+stat[i]+"',"); //appends , at end 
}
sb.append("'"+stat[stat.length-1]+"'"); // append last element
```

Comment: "Try this" why? What are you trying to demonstrate with this answer? Dumping code isn't useful: you need to explain what you're doing differently.

Comment: Sure. I'm gonna explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `deleteChartAt` method: 
`sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);`

For example:

```
String[] stat = req.getParameterValues("status");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(200);

if(stat!=null) {
    for(int i=0;i<stat.length;i++){
        sb.append("'"+stat[i]+"',");
    }
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1); //---------> This will remove the last comma
    String app = "WHERE status in ("+sb.toString()+")";
    String sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM Table "+app+";";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try something this.

```
 for(int i=0;i<stat.length;i++){

        sb.append("'"+stat[i]+"'");
            if(i!=stat.length-1){
              sb.append(",");
            }

        }
```

Comment: downvoter please provide the reason for your vote so that i can improve on it.

Answer (score -1):

try
    String app = "WHERE status in ("+sb.substring(0, sb.length()-2)+")";