# select multiple IDs from database using java

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I have a table where I can select a single entry like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1;
```

I know that I could easily select entries by multiple ids like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3);
```

But now I have implemented this in Java with MariaDB/J Connector, using `java.sql` classes:

```
public ArrayDeque<DataType> getItems(long... ids) {
    ArrayDeque<DataType> deque = new ArrayDeque<DataType>();
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        st = getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = ?;");
        st.setLong(1, id);
        resultSet = st.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            deque.add(parseResultSetToDataType(resultSet));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close(resultSet, st);
    }
    return deque;
}
```

Now, basically I need to put a `?` for every variable I want to insert. Since the amount of selected Ids can vary, I can't put a static `IN (?,?,?)` there. The dirty solution that comes to my mind is generate `(?,?,?)` based on the size of `long... ids` -- but is there a better, 'cleaner' solution to this?

Comment: Other than using a library on top of JDBC that does that for you, no.

Comment: PreparedStatement has a `setArray` method that can be used for this purpose with some databases. Unfortunately, several database drivers, including MySql's, don't support it.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause), it might help as few options explained there.

Answer (score -1):

```
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("Select * from table where id in (?)");
    Array array = statement.getConnection().createArrayOf("int", new Object[]{1, 2,3});
    statement.setArray(1, array);
```

Comment: MySql's jdbc driver does not support the setArray method

Comment: Good question - why don't you try it out and let us know?