# Does h2 have a query/clause similar to the WHERE IN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, h2, where-in

My code currently goes as follows:

```
public List<DeviceOrganizationMetadataHolder> getChildrenByParentId(List<String> parentIds) throws DeviceOrganizationDAOException {
        List<DeviceOrganizationMetadataHolder> children = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection conn;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        DeviceOrganizationMetadataHolder deviceMetadataHolder;
        String[] data = parentIds.toArray(new String[parentIds.size()]);
        try {
            conn = this.getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM DEVICE_ORGANIZATION_MAP WHERE DEVICE_PARENT IN (?)";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            data = parentIds.toArray(data);
            stmt.setObject(1, data);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                deviceMetadataHolder = this.loadOrganization(rs);
                children.add(deviceMetadataHolder);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DeviceOrganizationDAOException("Error occurred for device list with while retrieving children.", e);
        } finally {
            DeviceManagementDAOUtil.cleanupResources(stmt, rs);
            return children;
        }
}
```

However even though in the unit tests I try to pass an array with parentIds, the return remains null.
What I can gauge from this is one of the following:

1. The **array data isn't getting properly read**, therefore the output is coming as null.
2. **WHERE IN is not supported by h2** or **else there is a different implementation** that needs to be used instead.

Where am I going wrong in this?

EDIT - There was a similar [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause) that was tagged. While it suggested using a StringBuilder and a loop, I was looking for an answer stating how it could be done in a cleaner way using the query itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PreparedStatement with list of parameters in a IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the parameter as a list instead of an array, ie replace

```
stmt.setObject(1, data);
```

with

```
stmt.setObject(1, Arrays.asList(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

There was an [issue](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/149) posted on the h2database GitHub about this exact problem. Followed the suggested edits and **it worked**!

Code after edits is as follows:

```
public List<DeviceOrganizationMetadataHolder> getChildrenByParentId(List<String> parentIds) throws DeviceOrganizationDAOException {
        List<DeviceOrganizationMetadataHolder> children = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection conn;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        DeviceOrganizationMetadataHolder deviceMetadataHolder;
        Object[] data = parentIds.toArray();
        try {
            conn = this.getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM DEVICE_ORGANIZATION_MAP WHERE DEVICE_PARENT IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(x VARCHAR = ?))";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setObject(1, data);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                deviceMetadataHolder = this.loadOrganization(rs);
                children.add(deviceMetadataHolder);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DeviceOrganizationDAOException("Error occurred for device list with while retrieving children.", e);
        } finally {
            DeviceManagementDAOUtil.cleanupResources(stmt, rs);
            return children;
        }
}
```

As you can see, I've used an Object array for data instead and added an additional query inside the main query.
Followed the instructions given in the GitHub issue to a tee and it worked flawlessly.