# IN clause in Apache Camel 2.18

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql

I am trying to execute a sql deletion statement within the route. The query contains an IN clause and I want to pass a Set of values to the IN clause. I am using camel-core & camel-jdbc 2.18.1 and camel-sql 2.18.0

```
from("direct:deleteRoute").setBody(simple("DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID IN (:#in:idSet)")).to(Constants.JDBC_DATA_SOURCE).end();
```

Value for idSet is passed in the header of the exchange with key `idSet` from the route, which calls `direct:deleteRoute`.

But when I execute I get the following exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: A syntax error has occurred.
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:408)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.a(IfxSqli.java:3132)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.D(IfxSqli.java:3412)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2325)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2250)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeExecute(IfxSqli.java:2153)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeExecute(IfxSqli.java:2133)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.b(IfxResultSet.java:362)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.a(IfxStatement.java:1144)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeImpl(IfxStatement.java:1120)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.c(IfxStatement.java:866)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.execute(IfxStatement.java:784)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.doCreateAndExecuteSqlStatement(JdbcProducer.java:220)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.createAndExecuteSqlStatement(JdbcProducer.java:125)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.processingSqlBySettingAutoCommit(JdbcProducer.java:86)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.process(JdbcProducer.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:192)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:76)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: null
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:408)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.D(IfxSqli.java:3417)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you share what is in `Constants.JDBC_DATA_SOURCE` variable? Because from stacktrace it seems, it is JDBC component, but you have used parameter syntax for SQL component. SQL component uses `:#` for parameter binding, JDBC component uses `:?`. And just a note: never ever mix dependency versions, it may lead to unpredictable behavior. Always use all components in version same as is Apache Camel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stacktrace comes from [`camel-jdbc`](http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html) component. This component uses the standard JDBC API, so it takes some limitations from it. One of this is, that you [cannot pass collection as single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause). 
<sup><sub>In Camel, you can implement custom [JdbcPrepareStatementStrategy](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.12.0/camel-jdbc/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/jdbc/JdbcPrepareStatementStrategy.html), register it with uri parameter prepareStatementStrategy to provide custom logic of parsing query, but I wouldn't suggest it. This can lead to lot of traps.</sub></sup>

Better use [`camel-sql`](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html) component, which uses `spring-jdbc` and allows this natively since Apache Camel 2.17.

**Example with constant prepared statement:**

```
from("direct:deleteIds")
        .to("sql:DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID IN (:#in:idSet)");
```

**Example with statement created from body:**

```
from("direct:deleteIds")
        .setBody(simple("DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID IN (:?in:idSet)")) // Note questionmark here for specifying parameter. This is difference against query in uri.  
        .to("direct:executeQuery");

from("direct:executeQuery")
        .setHeader(SqlConstants.SQL_QUERY, body())
        .to("sql:dummy?dataSource=#datasource");
```

Comment: Thanks @Bedla. I am working on spring boot and if I go ahead with using the second example what should be the value for #datasource. Is it the name of the bean which represents DataSource.

Comment: `#datasource` is a reference to look up the datasource from the registry (typically a Spring Bean name).