# Multiple result? MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I know how to get rows in MySQL, but what about if I have two rows with the same key and I want to get the two rows?

For example

```
"SELECT * FROM test WHERE (key_exaple = ?)"
```

The ps.setString(1, "test");

But let's imagine that I have two rows with the "test" key.

How can I get them one by one?

Comment: By iterating the rows with a `ResultSet`.

Comment: I'm don't have experience with sql, do you have an example?

Comment: [Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 'ps.' stands for PreparedStatement, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE key_exaple in (?, ?)

ps.setString(1, "test");
ps.setString(2, "second test");
```

[this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause)