# Java passing values into IN where clause

Tags: java

below string x can grow dynamically. So when I use setstring it throws error as *ORA-01722: invalid number*

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
String x= "'628','633','634','636','723'"

String grpStructure = "select grp_id, tkn_id from group_structure where grp_id in (?) order by grp_id";
            try (PreparedStatement pst = conn2.prepareStatement(groupStructure)) {
                ResultSet rs;
                pst.setString(1, x);
                rs = pst.executeQuery(); 
                while (rs.next()) {
                groupId = rs.getString("grp_id");
                tokenId= rs.getString("tkn_id");
                    System.out.println("group_id:" + grpId + "  token_id :"+tknId );
                }
            }
```

Comment: what is type grp_id ? Is it number or string in Table ?

Comment: refer this page
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause

Answer (score 0):

The `in` SQL clause accept an `Array` not a `String`. You should try with x values in an array of `String`

```
String[] x= new String[] { "628", "633", "634", "636", "723" };

String grpStructure = "select grp_id, tkn_id from group_structure where grp_id in (?) order by grp_id";
try (PreparedStatement pst = conn2.prepareStatement(groupStructure)) {
    ResultSet rs;
    pst.setArray(1, x);
    rs = pst.executeQuery(); 
    while (rs.next()) {
        groupId = rs.getString("grp_id");
        tokenId= rs.getString("tkn_id");
        System.out.println("group_id:" + grpId + "  token_id :"+tknId );
    }
}
```