# ArrayList in Java access Array of value in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a Java bean that has a field like below,

```
List<String> address = new ArrayList<>();
address.add("Pearl");
address.add("Granby");
```

I also have a table in MySQL database name building and a column name street of its own. when I use JDBC to connect to MySQL database, how can I use this ArrayList to query in MySQL database like SELECT * FROM building WHERE street IN ("Pearl", "Granby"). Or have any better query to execute this connect. Forgive me for my poor language.

I tried to connect directly and get error like:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'building.address IN [Pearl, Grandby]'
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am not quite sure what you are trying to do. Do you need **all** of the buildings that are on **any** of the streets in your `List`?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause) should help.

Comment: Yes, that's my target. I need to get all that is on any of the streets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String result = address.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"));
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe the result needs to concat() with the parentheses.