# cannot identify the missing right parenthesis

Tags: java, sql, selenium, select, syntax-error

Attempted to run the query from extracting data from a specific website, but picking up
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis instead.

```
public static void build(){
 Connection con = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;
 Statement stms = null;

 String buildXML ="";

 String list = lists.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','"));

 try {
  <<<database>>>
  <<<connection>>>

  rs = stmt.executeQuery("select name, type, dob, age, height, weight from peopleH where name in ('" + list + "') and age !=0 and dob !=0"); <-- *error here?!?*

  while(rs.next()){
   for(int i=0; lists.size() > i; i++){
     if(<<does not contain the name>>){
      <<<do this>>>
     }
     else {
      <<<do that>>>
     }
   }
  }
 }
catch(){
} finally{
}
}
```

What's meant to happen is that when data is filter and extracted via selenium (which is stored in an arrayList). The query above will query the arraylist and compare with the database against what is display on the selenium browser.

however the query above is pitching out missing right parenthesis...
I can't seem to find the issue here as last checked there is no addition , or invalid logic (in (***) and 'and' statement).

the data being filtered from selenium is printing out as expected
e.g john, sam, smith, mary, lili, happy

if placed in query it will be something like this

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select name, type, dob, age, height, weight from peopleH where name in ('john','sam','smith','mary','lili','happy') and age !=0 and dob !=0");
```

to something like this

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select name, type, dob, age, height, weight from peopleH where name in ('" + list + "') and age !=0 and dob !=0");
```

Comment: Maybe print out the `list` first check that it contains what you think it should.

Comment: Every item in the list needs to be surrounded with quotes instead of just the whole list.

Comment: Try `lists.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"))`

Comment: Use a prepared statement. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107044/preparedstatement-with-list-of-parameters-in-a-in-clause

Comment: Hello @ScaryWombat , GWR , ﾓｷｬﾃﾞ and FredvN 
Thank you for responding to my queries and apologies for the late response

I've taken into the above considerations and attempted to rewrote the codes again from scratch. Turns out there was an issue with my statement bit, as it was missing the right parenthesis (' ') which i somehow mention on here but not included the correct parenthesis in the code instead... *face palm + smh*