# preparedstatement with list of parameters for sql IN operator

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

I have an sql statement in an external properties file so it cannot be modified dynamically as some have suggested:

```
query = select distinct BSG_HANDLE FROM MYUSER.MYTABLE WHERE RATE_CODE IN (?) AND CORP = ?
```

A SOAP request provides the array of strings that will be used to populate the IN values.

```
public BsgHandleResponse getBsgHandleByRateCode(
@QueryParam("rateCodes") String rateCodes,
@QueryParam("corp") String corp)
```

Then I put them into the prepared statement like this:

```
ps = startTimedPreparedStatement(conn,SQL_FROM_PROPERTIES_FILE);
ps.setString(1, rateCodes);
ps.setString(2, corp);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

It works fine if rateCodes is a single string value like this:

```
25
```

but fails for multiple values like this:

```
25, 1P
```

I assume I have to do something like this instead

```
    public BsgHandleResponse getBsgHandleByRateCode(
    @QueryParam("rateCodes") final List<String> rateCodes,
    @QueryParam("corp") String corp)

    ps = startTimedPreparedStatement(conn,SQL_FROM_PROPERTIES_FILE);
    ps.setArray(1, rateCodes);
    ps.setString(2, corp);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

But I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PreparedStatement question in Java against Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510083/preparedstatement-question-in-java-against-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

[PreparedStatement question in Java against Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510083/preparedstatement-question-in-java-against-oracle)

Solution mention by @DJ works great but you have to take care of one edge case that there is limit on number of bind values you can have use with IN clause.
For oracle i think is close to 1K or 4K.

Comment: That looks like a clever solution.  Will try it out tomorrow and get back to you.  Thanks!