# SQL Get List of Substrings Then Use as Values for LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I want to use a list of substrings as the values for my `LIKE` clause.

Consider the following tables:

#### Strains (s)

```
id    name
-------------------------------------------------------
562   B6;129 (Bnip3 KO)
563   B6;129 (BNIP3 Wt) [pregnant]
564   B6;129 (BNIP3 Wt) [older than 21 days]
720   BALB/C T(x:11)38H (T38H)
721   BALB/C [older than 21 days]
```

#### Links (l)

```
id    protocol_id     strain_id
-------------------------------------------------------
1     61846           563
2     13487           564
3     79465           721
4     41699           720
```

#### Animals (a)

```
id    group_id        strain_id
-------------------------------------------------------
24    9666            563
25    9666            720
```

Normally I would provide a query that I've tried but this time I have nothing. Instead let me break down the steps I need to do:

1. Get a list of substrings from the name of the strain for all animals under the same `group_id`.

   - To get the substrings, I want the strings inside `(` and `)`
   - Something like `SELECT /* get the list of substrings */ FROM animals a LEFT JOIN strains s ON s.id = a.strain_id WHERE a.group_id = 9666`
   - In this example, I want the following list: `(BNIP3 Wt)` and `(T38H)`
   - In the case that there are multiple values that are enclosed in `(` and `)`, just use the last one
2. Use the resulting list above for the `LIKE` clause to get the list of `protocol_id` whose strain names contain the substrings.

#### My idea of a solution

```
SELECT l.protocol_id
FROM links l
LEFT JOIN strains s
ON s.id = l.strain_id
WHERE s.name LIKE (/* put the list here with the % for wildcards */)
```

The end result that I want to get is the following:

```
protocol_id
------------------------------
61846
13487
41699
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a large number of strings to match with oracle database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699223/how-to-load-a-large-number-of-strings-to-match-with-oracle-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f7fb1/13)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Strains (id, name ) AS
SELECT 562,   'B6;129 (Bnip3 KO)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 563,   'B6;129 (BNIP3 Wt) [pregnant]' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 564,   'B6;129 (BNIP3 Wt) [older than 21 days]' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 720,   'BALB/C T(x:11)38H (T38H)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 721,   'BALB/C [older than 21 days]' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Links (id, protocol_id, strain_id ) AS
SELECT 1,     61846,           563 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,     13487,           564 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,     79465,           721 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,     41699,           720 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Animals (id, group_id, strain_id ) AS
SELECT 24,    9666,            563 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 25,    9666,            720 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT l.protocol_id
FROM   links l
       INNER JOIN strains s
       ON s.id = l.strain_id
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( s.name, '\(.*?\)', 1, l.COLUMN_VALUE ) AS id
         FROM   strains s,
                TABLE( 
                  CAST(
                    MULTISET(
                      SELECT LEVEL
                      FROM   DUAL
                      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( s.name, '\(.*?\)' )
                    ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
                  )
                ) l,
                animals a
         WHERE  a.strain_id = s.id
         AND    a.group_id = 9666
       ) t
       ON s.name LIKE '%' || t.id || '%'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f7fb1/13/0)**:

```
| PROTOCOL_ID |
|-------------|
|       61846 |
|       13487 |
|       41699 |
|       41699 |
```

Comment: This looks great but how did you get the values you passed into `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST`?

Comment: The substrings for the strain names must not be hard-coded.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio Updated - add `DISTINCT` if you only want unique values.

Comment: Based on your SQL Fiddle I can confirm that this works. Is there a reason why you're not using `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`? I think those 2 should be enough (currently reading how to use them).

Comment: I tried your solution on my actual data and I'm getting a lot of `protocol_id` even with `DISTINCT`. Does your solution ignore rows where it doesn't find any `(` and `)`?

Comment: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f7fb1/16) - I added a small validation to make sure that there is a substring found. `INSTR(s.name, '(', 1, 1) > 0`. Thanks!

Comment: The regular expressions will check for `(` and `)` and will only return rows containing those patterns. Adding `INSTR` or `SUBSTR` is unnecessary and would just do exactly the same thing but in a much more convoluted way.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe solve the problem using REGEXP_LIKE

e.g.

```
With strains (id, name) as
(
          select 562,   'B6;129 (Bnip3 KO)' from dual
union all select 563,   'B6;129 (BNIP3 Wt) [pregnant]'  from dual
union all select 564,   'B6;129 (BNIP3 Wt) [older than 21 days]'  from dual
union all select 720,   'BALB/C T(x:11)38H (T38H)'  from dual
union all select 721,   'BALB/C [older than 21 days]'  from dual
)
    ,Links (id, protocol_id, strain_id ) as
(    
          select 1,     61846,           563 from dual
union all select 2,     13487,           564 from dual
union all select 3,     79465,           721 from dual
union all select 4,     41699,           720 from dual
)
   ,Animals (id, group_id, strain_id) as
(   
          select 24,    9666,            563 from dual
union all select 25,    9666,            720 from dual
)
SELECT l.protocol_id
FROM links l
LEFT JOIN strains s ON s.id = l.strain_id
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (s.name, '*BNIP3|T38H*');
```

Comment: Please don't hard-code the strain names. That won't work for me. I need to know how to get those values.

Comment: you can use REGEXP_SUBSTR to get the values