# how to select a list of 10,000 unique ids from dual in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, dual-table

So I can't create or edit tables (I'm a user with read only permission) and I want to look up 10,000 unique id's. I can't put them inside of an IN() statement because oracle limits over 1000 items.

Is it possible to select this entire list from the DUAL table in oracle? Something like:

```
select  
'id123,id8923,id32983,id032098,id308230,id32983289'  
from DUAL
```

Comment: It doesn't say anywhere that these are contiguous numbers. In fact the sample shows totally random numbers

Comment: You could also try `IN (SELECT C1 FROM (SELECT 'id123'  C1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 'id8923' FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 'id32983' FROM DUAL))`

Comment: Where are you getting those 10000 ids from? Isn't it a result of another query? Is it perhaps a list of all ids except for maybe a few?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a large number of strings to match with oracle database?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34699223/1509264)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS005) (they are not limited to 1000 items like an `IN` clause is):

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS id
FROM   TABLE(
         SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
           'id123', 'id8923', 'id32983', 'id032098', 'id308230', 'id32983289'
         )
       )
```

`SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` and `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST` are collection types that are supplied in the `SYS` schema.

You can join this directly to whichever table you are `SELECT`ing from without needing to use the `DUAL` table:

```sql
SELECT y.*
FROM   your_table y
       INNER JOIN TABLE(
         SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
           'id123', 'id8923', 'id32983', 'id032098', 'id308230', 'id32983289'
         )
       ) i
       ON (y.id = i.COLUMN_VALUE);
```

If you can get a collection type created then you do not even need the `TABLE` expression and can use it directly in the `WHERE` clause using the `MEMBER OF` operator:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
/
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  id MEMBER OF stringlist(
                      'id123', 'id8923', 'id32983', 'id032098', 'id308230', 'id32983289'
                    );
```

You can even pass the values as a bind parameter - see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle still doesn't support the `VALUES` row constructor, so there are only two ugly workarounds:

The 1000 item limit does not apply for multi-column IN conditions

[Expression Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E26088_02/expressions015.htm)

> A comma-delimited list of expressions can contain no more than 1000
>   expressions. A comma-delimited list of sets of expressions can contain
>   any number of sets, but each set can contain no more than 1000
>   expressions.

so you can do:

```
where (1,id) in ( (1,'id123'),
                  (1,'id8923'),
                  (1,'id32983'), 
                  (1,'id032098'), .... )
```

Or using a big ugly UNION ALL:

```
with idlist (xid) as (
  select 'id123' from dual union all 
  select 'id8923' from dual union all 
  .....
  select 'id32983' from dual 
)
select ...
from some_table
where id in (select xid from idlist);
```

Comment: Wow. How did you get to the multi-column work-around? Any documentation / official reference / semi-official reference?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: no I have no reference for that.

Comment: Can you recall where/when did you see it for the first time?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: I saw this here on SO

Comment: Did a quick search and add a reference to your answer. I hope it is O.K. by you.

Comment: wow what a strange thing, i guess i could write a function in excel to make this work, so great answer! in the end, i wrapped markovitz first answer inside a with() statement and got things running smooth :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is the WITH clause:

```
with ids as (
   select 'id123' as uid from dual union all
   select 'id8923' as uid from dual union all
   select 'id32983' as uid from dual union all
   select 'id032098' as uid from dual union all
   select 'id308230' as uid from dual union all
   select 'id32983289' as uid from dual 
)
select *
from ids
     join your_table yt
     on yt.id = ids.uid
```

This may seem like a bit of a chore but presumably you have your list of UIDs in a spreadsheet or whatever. If so it's a cinch to generate those select statements using regular expressions. Just cut'n'paste the column into an editor which supports regex search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another work-around

```
select  *

from    t

where   id in ('id1','id2','id3',...,'id1000')
     or id in ('id1001','id1002','id1003',...,'id2000')
     or id in ('id2001','id2002','id2003',...,'id3000')
     or ...
```