# Binding an array to the placeholders in a SQL query

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am trying to pass an array to my query placeholders but its not working as i expect. This is the query :

```
select * from A where id IN (1,2,3)
```

This is the PHP function :

```
$ids=['1','2','3'];
$result = $this->queryall_array(select * from A where id IN (?,?,?),$ids);
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to do that.
Thanks,

Comment: What RDBMS are you actually using? Please only tag that database. I'm not PHP savvy, but it looks like you are asking for 3 parameters and only passing 1.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Hi. I am using Oracle. I though that the function queryall_array() is auto convert the $ids to 3 parameters. This queryall_array() is something that one of my co-worker wrote.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Do you know how can i do that in this case. I have been trying to use implode() to add comma to $ids so i can have 3 parameters to pass to the ? instead of 1 now. But it did not work. Thanks

Comment: @WEI_DBA Never Mind. I got it works. After convert it to string with comma, I am passing directly inside IN. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: You can pass an [Oracle collection as a bind parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41161057/1509264) - here is [an example of how to do it in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264). No idea how to do it in PHP though.

Comment: @trinhdh. Very good! Can you update your post with your answer for future reference for others? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can't see the content of your custom queryall_array function but from the php documentation here is the correct way to do it with oracle:

```
$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $m = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($m['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn,"INSERT INTO mytab (id, text) VALUES(:id_bv, :text_bv)");

$id = 1;
$text = "Data to insert     ";
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":id_bv", $id);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":text_bv", $text);
oci_execute($stid);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php