# ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 error with myibatis

Tags: java, oracle, foreach, ibatis

I am writing an update query with IN clause in which I am passing List

```
update table set postcode={#postcode} where id in
<foreach collection="addresses" index="index" item="item" open="(" 
separator="," close=")">#{item}</foreach>
```

This runs fine when I have less than 1000 records in addresses.If there are more than 1000 records I get below error:

**ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000.**
How can this be handled?I came across some threads where they have handled in hibernate.How can I handle it with myibatis with more than 1000 records.

Comment: Use a collection [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41161057/1509264)] since they can handle more than 1000 items. Can't help with using collections in ibatis though but its built in Java and the first link shows how to pass a collection as a bind parameter it in Java.

Comment: @MT0 Can this be sorted at Java end..like checking first 1000 recordss and processing and then next 1000 records.Will it impact performance?

Comment: Why check for 1000 items and loop? Just pass all 948,732 items (or however many items you have) in a single collection and use a bind parameter to include it in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Store all those values into a separate table, and then use it in a subquery as

```
update table set
  postcode = some_value
where id in (select values from a_separate_table)
```

Comment: this syntax dosent work with myibatis update table set
  postcode = some_value
where id in (select values from a_separate_table)                                            Only foreach loop works

Comment: What a shame; unfortunately, I don't know *myibatis* so - someone else will, hopefully, assist.

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

This can't be handled until, you strict total number of expression in `IN` clause to less than `1000`.

Alternatively, you can split the query in multiple and your List as well and perform `UNION` to achieve same.