# Using :var with "IN" operator in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm usually working with MySQL or SQL Server and I've experienced quite a problem in Oracle SQL Developer.

I have query like this (making it simple just to replicate my issue):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.date > :START_DATE AND t1.date < :END_DATE AND t1.id IN (:IDS)
```

When I run this query, the dialog window opens and I'm prompted to enter the variables.

Problem is when I enter comma separated ids like `5,6,7` or with quotes `'5,6,7'` I get this error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Any ideas here?

PS: There has to be dialog prompt to enter variables. Colleagues are not SQL friendly. ;)

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://betteratoracle.com/posts/20-how-do-i-bind-a-variable-in-list

Comment: Man, thanks a lot. That's a solution I was looking for.

Comment: Have you encountered *any* language, that on being passed a single string parameter will decide to (automatically) inspect the contents, observe commas, and instead decide to treat it as multiple separate parameters? (and yet, strangely, people *keep* expecting this to be the behaviour in SQL)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It would behave like that if a substitution variable was used instead of a bind variable.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the bind variable `:ids` contains a literal value (rather than a list of literal values) so your query is:

```
AND t1.id IN ( '5,6,7' )
```

instead of:

```
AND t1.id IN ( 5, 6, 7 )
```

What you need to do is either [pass in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264) (which you could define from an array in an external language and pass in directly as a bind variable):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
/

SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.date > :START_DATE
AND   t1.date < :END_DATE
AND   t1.id MEMBER OF intlist( 5, 6, 7 )
```

Or compare the list using `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.date > :START_DATE
AND   t1.date < :END_DATE
AND   ',' || :ids || ',' LIKE '%,' || t1.id || ',%'
```

Or pass in a [delimited string literal and split that](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914140540/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings#t=201709141405407224393):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.date > :START_DATE
AND   t1.date < :END_DATE
AND   t1.id   IN ( SELECT TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( :ids, '\d+', 1, LEVEL ) )
                   FROM   DUAL
                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( :ids, '\d+' ) );
```

*(Or, a comma spearated list of numbers would work in the `IN` clause if you used a substitution variable instead of a bind variable.)*

Answer (score 0):

Are IDs NUMBERS or VARCHAR2?

This simple case works for me. Please try it:

```
select id from
(
select 1 id from dual
union
select 2 id from dual
union
select 3 id from dual
)
where id in (:IDS)
```

Comment: That's quite an ugly solution If you have queries like tens of rows long.

Comment: Its not a solution, just a sample to test if the parameter "IDS" work.