# How to pass variable in IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I declared the variable i_unit_attempt_status and I want to pass that variable in to 'In clause'. How can I do that?

```
INNER JOIN student_unit_attempt sua
on sua.person_id=sei.person_id
   AND sua.course_cd=sei.course_cd
   AND sua.unit_cd=sei.unit_cd
   AND (sua.unit_attempt_status in (l_unit_attempt_status))
```

Data in the variable will be:

```
Option 1:'COMPLETED','DISCONTIN','DUPLICATE','ENROLLED','INVALID','UNCONFIRM'
Option 2: 'ENROLLED'
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to give an example of the value that `l_unit_attempt_status` has?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using :var with "IN" operator in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128459/using-var-with-in-operator-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44129834/1509264)

Use `LIKE`:

```sql
INNER JOIN student_unit_attempt sua
on sua.person_id=sei.person_id
   AND sua.course_cd=sei.course_cd
   AND sua.unit_cd=sei.unit_cd
   AND ','||l_unit_attempt_status||',' LIKE '%,'''||sua.unit_attempt_status||''',%'
```

Or pass in a collection:

```sql
CREATE TYPE status_list IS TABLE OF varchar2(20);

DECLARE
  l_unit_attempt_status status_list := status_list( 'COMPLETED','DISCONTIN','DUPLICATE','ENROLLED','INVALID','UNCONFIRM' );
BEGIN
  SELECT <your_column_list>
  INTO   <variables>
  FROM   table_name sei
         INNER JOIN student_unit_attempt sua
         on sua.person_id=sei.person_id
            AND sua.course_cd=sei.course_cd
            AND sua.unit_cd=sei.unit_cd
            AND sua.unit_attempt_status MEMBER OF l_unit_attempt_status;
END;
/
```

Or split the list:

```sql
INNER JOIN student_unit_attempt sua
on sua.person_id=sei.person_id
   AND sua.course_cd=sei.course_cd
   AND sua.unit_cd=sei.unit_cd
   AND sua.unit_attempt_status in ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
                                    FROM   XMLTABLE( l_unit_attempt_status ) )
```