# Unable to pass string value 1,2 as input to an oracle query

Tags: oracle, bind-variables

Below is my query and i am passing a string value 1,2 as bind value but it is showing an error as it is not a valid number. I know IN accepts only number but here i need to pass the string value

```
SELECT  e.*
FROM    employee_detail e
WHERE   e.emp_id IN (:emp_id)
```

Comment: Are you after dynamic in-lists? If so, maybe [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dynamic-in-lists) would be of use to you?

Comment: I'm afraid you must tell us more. I tried to use string- bind variables via Lazarus and there was no Problem. I got it right: You want to pass exactly 1 string value "1,2" to this query?

Comment: qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM BLABLA WHERE BLA IN (:P1)';
    qry.ParamByName('P1').AsString := '1,2';
    qry.Active:=true;

Comment: Simply put, you can't do that. Oracle does not allow comma-separated lists of numbers to be passed as strings.

Comment: [How to load a large number of strings to match with oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264) gives an example of how to bind an array of values to an Oracle collection using Java. Linked off that question are multiple others which deal with similar topics to this question.

Answer (score 1):

`In` is used with `list of values` or `subqueries`.

You can convert a comma separeted `string` into a `subquery`, by using the following *hack*:

```
 SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(temp, '[^,]+', 1, level))   
    FROM (SELECT  :emp_id temp FROM DUAL)
    CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(temp, '[^,]+')
```

Here the `1,2,3` sting will be converted into `subquery` that returns `3` rows.

So, the end result, for your case, could be something like this:

```
SELECT  e.*
FROM    employee_detail e
WHERE   e.emp_id in (
SELECT decode(:emp_id,null,  (select  e.emp_id from dual) 
,TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(temp, '[^,]+', 1, level)) )  
    FROM (SELECT  :emp_id temp FROM DUAL)
    CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(temp, '[^,]+'))
```

Note that in this case  `In` will return `true` if `:emp_id` is `null` and  this was deliberatly achieved by using `decode` function.

Comment: `IN` is not used with collections it is [used with either an expression list or a subquery](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm). `MEMBER OF` is [used with collections](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjcol.htm#sthref512).

Comment: @MT0 OK, thanks for the correction, regarding the term I used. It is indeed subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string comparisons instead of an IN condition.

```
select ...
from   ...
where  ',' || :emp_id || ',' like '%,' || to_char(emp_id) || ',%'
;
```