# How to pass varchar with single quotes to Stored Proc in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have stored procedure called like this:

call packagename.StoredProc('''A'',''B''')

'A', 'B' part is then meant to be used as parameter in procedure's code in the IN clause.

When I run that code with in clause as `paramvalue IN ('A', 'B')` it returns rows as expected.

But when call to stored proc is executed no rows which makes me think those quotes must be wrong but I can't get it right apparently. Can anyone see why is this not working? Thanks

Code from proc:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
            INTO v_PendingCheckCount
            FROM FUND_CHANGE_REQUEST
            WHERE STATUS IN ('PENDING_CHK', 'PEND_2ND_CHK')
            AND PROVIDER IN (pProviderList);
```

Proc call:

```
CALL PackageName.ProcedureName('''A'',''B''')
```

pProviderList is parameter passed to procedure.

Comment: Are you passing pProviderList as VARCHAR ? Something like- CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName(pProviderList VARCHAR).

Comment: Yes it is passed as Varchar2

Comment: I think your problem is that the string you pass into the procedure is not being parsed as a comma-delimited list - it's nothing to do with the single quotes.  You could prove this by using DBMS_OUTPUT to print the parameter value - pretty sure you'll see the single quotes.

Comment: Probable duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34699223/1509264), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44778342/1509264), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35231757/1509264) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35648999/1509264)

Comment: Obviously a _single string_ that happens to contain SQL syntax is not the same thing as an actual list of separate values. It would be completely disastrous if it worked that way. I am puzzled that anyone would find this puzzling.

Comment: @William, I am junior you see. :) And was given the code already written and task to find out why it is not working.

Comment: Fair enough, we were all beginners once. I'm just wondering if there is any computer language that behaves that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a collection not a string and use `MEMBER OF` rather than `IN`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE characterlist IS TABLE OF CHAR(1);
/

CREATE PACKAGE your_package AS
  PROCEDURE countPending(
    pProviderList IN  characterlist
    pCount        OUT INTEGER
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO pCount
    FROM FUND_CHANGE_REQUEST
    WHERE STATUS IN ('PENDING_CHK', 'PEND_2ND_CHK')
    AND PROVIDER  MEMBER OF pProviderList;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then you can call it as:

```
DECLARE
  vCount INTEGER;
BEGIN
  your_package.countPending(
    characterlist( 'A', 'B' ),
    vCount
  );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( vCount );
END;
/
```

> Can anyone see why is this not working?

You are passing a single string and not a list of values - so the `IN` condition is testing to see whether the `PROVIDER` column exactly matches your entire input string and not, as you are assuming, each element of your quoted delimited list.

```
 WHERE 'A' IN ( q'['A', 'B']' )
```

Will never match since neither `'A'` does not equal `q'['A', 'B']'` (or `'''A'', ''B'''`) and the count will always be zero.

```
 WHERE 'A' IN ( 'A', 'B' )
```

Will match but there are two terms in the expression list of the `IN` condition.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. We got it working replacing IN clause with INSTR which seems to be the simplest. So it went like this: INSTR(pProviderList, PROVIDER, 1, 1) > 0.  I would imagine your solution would work much faster on bigger data, so I'm accepting your answer. And also thank for explaining why it didn't work with IN.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot (well, you can, but it'll be considered as one string literal, not a list of values) use a pure string of comma separated values in the `IN` clause of the query. What you can(should) do in this case (as one of the options) is to turn your comma separated string in a collection and use it accordingly. Here is an example:

**Note**: Here I have used built-in `apex_application_global` `vc_arr2` collection. 
      You might decide to create your own. It's up to you.
      You might need to be granted `execute` privilege on `apex_util` package if you choose to use it.

Just a demonstration

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
   -- your source string
   l_str varchar2(100) := 'X, B, C';
   -- collection  the source string will be turned into  
   l_str_tab apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
   l_result number;
 begin
   -- convert the comma separated string of values
   -- into a collection 

   l_str_tab := apex_util.string_to_table(l_str, ',');

   -- Querying the collection using TABLE operator
   -- and passing result into the IN clause of the main query 

   select count(*)
     into l_result
     from dual
    where dummy in (select column_value
                      from table(l_str_tab));

    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_result));                  
 end;
```

Result:

```
1
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: If `apex_util.string_to_table` is a collection (and not a `VARRAY`) then you can simplify it (as per [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44799087/1509264)) to get rid of the table collection expression and instead use `WHERE dummy MEMBER OF l_str_tab`

Comment: There are plenty of non-apex ways of splitting a delimited string - there is an entire [SO documentation page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings) on it including [this PL/SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings/6447/splitting-strings-using-a-pl-sql-function).

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. I found your solution little harder to read compared to MT0's and also likely coworkers wouldn't know apex_util and I like to keep thing as simple as possible.