# Bind an array to placeholder in Oralce SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer when I want to provide a list of values to a single placeholder SQL developer reads them as one value. 
e.g

```
select *  from some_table where some_value in (:list_of_values);
```

When I enter 1,2,3 into the Value text box it oracle reads all 1,2,3 as one
 value 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this is an answer to the [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47352403/1) of the question which has been significantly changed by edits.*

> What do I need to put in the text box below ?

There is nothing that you can put into the text box to generate multiple columns when you are using a bind variable since a bind variable represents a single value.

If you change your query to use a [substitution variable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB):

```
select &ary from dual;
```

Then you can enter `1,2,3` in the dialog box and you will get the output:

```
1 2 3
- - -
1 2 3
```

Comment: Ok, what if the query what something 'where value in (:array)' ?

Comment: @Adelin See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778342/unable-to-pass-string-value-1-2-as-input-to-an-oracle-query) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231757/pl-sql-use-list-variable-in-where-in-clause) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242771/oracle-stored-procedure-with-parameters-for-in-clause) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648999/where-in-condition-not-accepting-string-value) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44798614/1509264). That particular question has been asked (and closed as a duplicate) many many times.

Comment: I don't think the question is duplicated as I am asking about Oracle SQL Developer for Oracle in general

Comment: @Adelin Using SQL Developer or TOAD or Java does not change how a bind variable behaves. An answer for one of those IDEs is an answer for all of them.

Comment: I don't agree with you, because in java if I replace :list_of_values with '1,2,3' it will actually work the way it should :)

Comment: It is like Sql Develop reads the provided value of 1,2,3 as '1,2,3','other_values', '....'  Not like 1,2,3

Comment: @Adelin No - In Java, if you use `PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE '1' IN (:ary)" ); st.setString("1,2,3");ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();` then you will not get any results back as `'1'` does not equal `'1,2,3'`. *A bind variable is a single value in all IDEs*.

Comment: "if I replace :list_of_values with '1,2,3'" then you are not using a bind variable `:list_of_values` you are using a substitution variable `&list_of_values`.